# View Notability .note files on my Mac

Tags: ipad

I use Notability, a journal app, on my iPad and backup my documents to Dropbox using the app's proprietary `.note` format. How can I read my `.note` files on my Macbook? I am willing to convert the files to another format before reading them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of a few weeks ago there is [a Mac OS X version of Notability](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/notability/id736189492?mt=12).

You might also be interested what [Gingerlabs says about it](http://support.gingerlabs.com/customer/portal/topics/697216-mac/articles) (FAQ).

Answer (score 1):

If the `note` format is just a plain text (`txt`) documents, you can probably open them with **TextEdit**. But if it’s in `plist` format, or other binary data, you can only open them when the developer build the desktop version accompanying your iPad version.

Comment: See jeff hayes' answer. Gingerlabs released a version of Notability for Mac OSX since you wrote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using Notability you can export or choose to Back up  your files in PDF format. You can open PDF files on your Mac using Preview.

Answer (score 1):

Change the of the file to a .txt and you can open it. So for example 'name.note' becomes name.txt. The extension will change and text editor will be able to open it